# Combinations by group in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have a question about combinations by group.

My mini-sample looks like this:

```
sample <- data.frame(
  group=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b"),
  number=c(1,2,3,2,4,5,3)
)
```

If I apply the function of `combn`to the data frame,it gives me following result, which is all the combinations of the values under the 'number' column regardless of which group the value belongs to:

```
         [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    1    2
   [2,]    1    3
   [3,]    1    2
   [4,]    1    4
   [5,]    1    5
   [6,]    1    3
   [7,]    2    3
   [8,]    2    2
   [9,]    2    4
  [10,]    2    5
  [11,]    2    3
  [12,]    3    2
  [13,]    3    4
  [14,]    3    5
  [15,]    3    3
  [16,]    2    4
  [17,]    2    5
  [18,]    2    3
  [19,]    4    5
  [20,]    4    3
  [21,]    5    3
```

The code that I used for the results above is as follows:

```
t(combn((sample$number), 2))
```

However, I would like to get the combination results within the group (i.e., "a", "b"). Therefore, the result that I want to get should look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   a    1    2
[2,]   a    1    3
[3,]   a    1    2
[4,]   a    2    3
[5,]   a    2    2
[6,]   a    3    2
[7,]   b    4    5
[8,]   b    4    3
[9,]   b    5    3
```

In addition to the combinations, I would like to get the column indicating
the group.

Answer (score 4):

We can use a group by function with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample)[, {i1 <-  combn(number, 2)
                   list(i1[1,], i1[2,]) }, by =  group]
#    group V1 V2
#1:     a  1  2
#2:     a  1  3
#3:     a  1  2
#4:     a  2  3
#5:     a  2  2
#6:     a  3  2
#7:     b  4  5
#8:     b  4  3
#9:     b  5  3
```

Or a compact option would be

```
setDT(sample)[, transpose(combn(number, 2, FUN = list)), by = group]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
 lst <- by(sample$number, sample$group, FUN = combn, m= 2)
 data.frame(group = rep(unique(as.character(sample$group)), 
                        sapply(lst, ncol)), t(do.call(cbind, lst)))
```

Comment: isn't `levels(sample$group)` more readable than `unique(as.character(sample$group))` ?

Comment: @jiggunjer Yes, but needs to consider the order as well

Answer (score 4):

Here's a base R option using (1) `split` to create a list of data.frames per unique group-entry, (2) `lapply` to loop over each list element and compute the combinations using `combn`, (3) `do.call(rbind, ...)` to collect the list elements back into a single `data.frame`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(sample, sample$group), {
   function(x) data.frame(group = x$group[1], t(combn(x$number, 2)))
}))

#    group X1 X2
#a.1     a  1  2
#a.2     a  1  3
#a.3     a  1  2
#a.4     a  2  3
#a.5     a  2  2
#a.6     a  3  2
#b.1     b  4  5
#b.2     b  4  3
#b.3     b  5  3
```

And a dplyr option:

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>% group_by(group) %>% do(data.frame(t(combn(.$number, 2))))
#Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
#Groups: group [2]
#
#   group    X1    X2
#  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)
#1      a     1     2
#2      a     1     3
#3      a     1     2
#4      a     2     3
#5      a     2     2
#6      a     3     2
#7      b     4     5
#8      b     4     3
#9      b     5     3
```

Comment: what's the alternative to do() as it is superseded