# tidyr - unique way to get combinations (using tidyverse only)

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I wanted to get all unique pairwise combinations of a unique string column of a dataframe using the `tidyverse` (ideally).

Here is a dummy example:

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- letters[1:3] %>% 
        tibble::as_tibble()
a
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   value
#>   <chr>
#> 1     a
#> 2     b
#> 3     c

tidyr::crossing(a, a) %>% 
    magrittr::set_colnames(c("words1", "words2"))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   words1 words2
#>    <chr>  <chr>
#> 1      a      a
#> 2      a      b
#> 3      a      c
#> 4      b      a
#> 5      b      b
#> 6      b      c
#> 7      c      a
#> 8      c      b
#> 9      c      c
```

Is there a way to remove 'duplicate' combinations here. That is have the output be the following in this example:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   words1 words2
#>    <chr>  <chr>
#> 1      a      b
#> 2      a      c
#> 3      b      c
```

I was hoping there would be a nice `purrr::map` or `filter` approach to pipe into to complete the above.

EDIT: There are similar questions to this one e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221588/combinations-by-group-in-r), marked by @Sotos. Here I am specifically looking for tidyverse (`purrr`, `dplyr`) ways to complete the pipeline I have setup. The other answers use various other packages that I do not want to include as dependencies.

Comment: @Sotos - I read that question already. I am specifically asking this question to use tidyverse packages and in particular purrr::map solutions. Please remove the duplication flag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

wish there was a better way, but I usually use this...

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(value = letters[1:3])

df %>% 
  expand(value, value1 = value) %>% 
  filter(value < value1)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   value value1
#   <chr> <chr> 
# 1 a     b     
# 2 a     c     
# 3 b     c
```

Comment: I am trying to solve the same issue but now getting the problem `Error: Column name `value` must not be duplicated.` when I use your solution :-(

Comment: edited to work with current tidyverse version (tidyverse recently implemented new/stricter column name checking)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
tidyr::crossing(a, a) %>% 
  magrittr::set_colnames(c("words1", "words2")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(words1 = sort(c(words1, words2))[1],       # sort order of words for each row
         words2 = sort(c(words1, words2))[2]) %>%
  filter(words1 != words2) %>%                      # remove word combinations with itself
  unique()                                          # remove duplicates

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  words1 words2
   <chr>  <chr>
1      a      b
2      a      c
3      b      c
```