# How do I setup data for tidygraph and ggraph?

Tags: r, dplyr, ggraph, tidygraph

I'm wanting to run a network analysis but am completely lost at how to get my data structured correctly, since most examples already have data structured at the `to` and `from` level.

An example of my data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Alice", "Ben", "Tom", "Jane", "Neil", "Alice", "Tom", "Ben", "Jane", "Neil", "Alice", "Tom", "Ben", "Jane", "Bob"),
         Location = c("Ward", "Desk", "Op", "Call", "Off",
                      "Ward", "Desk", "Op", "Call", "Off",
                      "Ward", "Desk", "Op", "Call", "Off"),
         Rating = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8))
```

I now wish to get `to` and `from` combinations of people, as denoted by `Name`, for every `Rating`. You will also note that people can be at a different `Location` during a different rating, although I'd prefer to for this, in combination with `Name` to be the nodes and `Rating` to be the edges.

I have looked at `library(iterpc)` but am struggling to comprehend the whole combination thing, with five different lineups.

Is there a potential `dplyr` solution to my problem? Thank you!

EDIT: It looks as though my question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491410/tidyr-unique-way-to-get-combinations-using-tidyverse-only) yet the answer marked does not work for me, instead I get `Error: Column name Name must not be duplicated.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `from` column to be `Name` and the `to` column to be your `Rating` column, then tidygraph does this mapping for you.

```r
library(tidygraph)
#> Warning: package 'tidygraph' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter

df <- data.frame(
  Name = c(
    "Alice", "Ben", "Tom", "Jane", "Neil",
    "Alice", "Tom", "Ben", "Jane", "Neil",
    "Alice", "Tom", "Ben", "Jane", "Bob"
  ),
  Location = c(
    "Ward", "Desk", "Op", "Call", "Off",
    "Ward", "Desk", "Op", "Call", "Off",
    "Ward", "Desk", "Op", "Call", "Off"
  ),
  Rating = c(
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8)
)

tg <- as_tbl_graph(df)
tg
#> # A tbl_graph: 11 nodes and 15 edges
#> #
#> # A directed acyclic multigraph with 4 components
#> #
#> # Node Data: 11 x 1 (active)
#>   name 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 Alice
#> 2 Ben  
#> 3 Tom  
#> 4 Jane 
#> 5 Neil 
#> 6 Bob  
#> # ... with 5 more rows
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 15 x 3
#>    from    to Rating
#>   <int> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     7      1
#> 2     2     8      1
#> 3     3     9      1
#> # ... with 12 more rows
```

You can double-check this mapping is done correctly by looking at the first row of your edge table and see an edge between `1` and `7`, which are `Alice` and `Ward`, which is the first row in your original data frame.

```
data.frame(tg)
#>     name
#> 1  Alice
#> 2    Ben
#> 3    Tom
#> 4   Jane
#> 5   Neil
#> 6    Bob
#> 7   Ward
#> 8   Desk
#> 9     Op
#> 10  Call
#> 11   Off
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>