# How to collect all combinations of characters in vectors as a list of vectors of characters?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, split

Lets say I have two vectors:

```
x <- c("A", "B")
y <- c("C")
```

I would then like to find and collect all combinations of `x` and `y` in the following manner:

```
DesiredOutput <- list(c('A', 'C'), c('B', 'C'))
```

I have tried using `expand.grid` in combination with `split` as follows:

```
xy.df <- expand.grid(x, y)
xy.list <- split(xy.df, 1:nrow(xy.df))
```

However, this does not produce the desired output as for instance `xy.list[[1]][1]` is no longer a character. And if I try to simply do `as.character(xy.list[[1]][1])` then this returns a `"1"`.  So, what can I do instead?

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221588/combinations-by-group-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer in stackoverflow.com/questions/38221588/combinations-by-group-in-r  you could try:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

  
  df1 <- data.frame(x, y) |> 
    pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
    distinct() |> 
    group_by(name)
    
    as.data.frame(t(combn(df1$value, 2)))
#>   V1 V2
#> 1  A  C
#> 2  A  B
#> 3  C  B
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>